# PHP rotated image is blank

Tags: php, ios, image, rotation

I'm using the following php code to save images from various devices. All works fine except iPhone images appearing sideways. I have found a way to fix this by rotating the image before it's saved. However when I upload the image it does not appear on my webpage and in my file manager it still appears sideways. Am I targeting the wrong file to rotate? Or am I using something else incorrectly?
Here's my code:

```
    $file = $_FILES["newsnap"];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $aboutitems = nl2br(mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_POST['about-snap']));
    $uploadloc = mkdir("../$username/");
    $image_temp = $_FILES["newsnap"]['tmp_name'];//Temporary location
    $filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, htmlentities($file["name"]));


            $sourcePath = $image_temp; //  source path of the file


            $exif = exif_read_data($sourcePath);
            $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];

            switch($orientation) 
                {
                    case 3:
                        $sourcePath = imagerotate($sourcePath, 180, 0);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $sourcePath = imagerotate($sourcePath, -90, 0);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        $sourcePath = imagerotate($sourcePath, 90, 0);
                        break;
                }

            $targetPath = "../$username/$filename"; // Target path where file is to be stored

            move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file

            $added = date("y.m.d");

            mysqli_query($database, "INSERT INTO piqs(userid, chicpiq, aboutpic, added) VALUES('$id', '$targetPath', '$aboutitems', '$added')");
```

The code works perfectly fine without the below code. I added code below only to rotate a sideways image:

```
            $exif = exif_read_data($sourcePath);
            $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];

            switch($orientation) 
                {
                    case 3:
                        $sourcePath = imagerotate($sourcePath, 180, 0);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $sourcePath = imagerotate($sourcePath, -90, 0);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        $sourcePath = imagerotate($sourcePath, 90, 0);
                        break;
                }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When I see it correctly `$sourcePath` is a variable to the file *path*, which can't be rotated...

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php, you have to pass the opened resourcere of the picture. So you have to do something like this

```
$oldImage = ImageCreateFromJPEG($sourcePath);
switch($orientation){
    case 3:
        $newImage = imagerotate($oldImage, 180, 0);
        break;
    case 6:
        $newImage = imagerotate($oldImage, -90, 0);
        break;
    case 8:
        $newImage = imagerotate($oldImage, 90, 0);
        break;
    default:
        $newImage = $oldImage;
}
imagejpeg($newImage, $targetPath, 90);
```

Comment: Hi Fabian. Thank you for pointing this out. I'm testing this now. So far I can see a small change but now the image is displayed sideways also on iPhone and desktop (earlier it was sideways on desktop but was okay on iPhone). I'm going to try a few things and will update my code. Could you have a look later again? Cheers man

Comment: Nope, you first call `$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp)` (forget that path in the var name, it will only confuse), it will return a "resource". Then you rotate this resource, so you call `$imageRotated = imagerotate($source, -90, 0);`. In this variable you have the rotated image resource. With `imagejpeg($imageRotated, $targetPath, 90);`, you will write the new image to `$targetPath` (it does not matter when you calculate this). Afterwards, you do not have to move the file, because, you already copied the file via graphicprocessing.